# Execute Php script in C

Tags: c, exec

I am creating a simple webserver in C and trying to execute php scripts. I was able to execute this by calling:
    execl("/usr/bin/php", "/usr/bin/php", "-q",phpFile ,(char *) NULL);

However i am having trouble on sending get parameters to this file. eg: ./index.php?name=test
How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just append the arguments at the end of the php file ? 
I think something like that should work :

```
    char phpFile [128] = "./index.php";
    char * args = "name=test";
    char * args2 = "city=paris";
    strcat(phpFile, "?");
    strcat(phpFile, args);
    strcat(phpFile, "&");
    strcat(phpFile, args2); //  etc. if you want to add more args.
```

Comment: I could do that. But execl doesnt give appropriate result for that